# How to write this LINQ ( or SQL) query?

Tags: database, linq, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

> **News**
>
> Id
>
> Title
>
> LanguageId

Language table:

> **Languages**
>
> Id
>
> Name
>
> IsDefault

Now with LanguageId as parameter (for example en-US), and the default language is en-GB, I want to get value like this:

> **News**
>
> *Id*  *Title*  *LanguageId*
>
> 1     1     en-US
>
> 2     2     en-US
>
> ...remaining en-US news...
>
> 10   10    en-GB
>
> 11   11    en-GB
>
> ...remaining en-GB news, as en-GB is default...
>
> 20   20    fr-FR
>
> 21   21    fr-FR
>
> ...other news in remaining language ...

The current solution is using temp table and cursors to fetch out news for each language. Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the right order for languages is the key here (which resembles what you've got):

```cs
from lang in db.Languages
order by lang.LanguageId == languageId descending,
         lang.IsDefault descending,
         lang.Name
```

Then add the join:

```cs
from lang in db.Languages
join newsItem in db.NewsItems on lang.LanguageId equals newsItem.LanguageId
order by lang.LanguageId == languageId descending,
         lang.IsDefault descending,
         lang.Name
select new { newsItem.Id, newsItem.Title, lang.Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an order by statement to your tsql like below.

```
ORDER BY CASE LanguageId WHEN 'en-US' THEN 0 WHEN 'en-GB' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

Answer (score 0):

After some works, my LINQ query is:

```
List<News> GetNews(string languageId)
{
    var languages = db.Languages.ToDictionary(l => l.Id, l => l.IsDefault);
    var news = db.News.Where(<filter condition>).ToList(); //(otherwise LINQ to Entities will not be able to recognize my custom function)
        news = news.OrderByDescending(n=>n.LanguageId == languageId).ThenByDescending(n=> OrderByLang(a.LanguageId, languages)).ToList();
}


private bool OrderByLang(string languageId, Dictionary<string, bool> languages)
{
                return (languages[languageId]);
}
```

It works as expected, but it requires to return the whole table to the application layer for paging, which is not very optiomal. Any other suggestions?